# SQL Server differential backups in a Simple recovery model

Tags: sql-server, backup

I created full backup on 1/1/2021. Then i stopped doing full backups.
For a month I was doing just differential backups.

If I restore full backup with norecovery,
would I be able to restore 2/2/2021 differential backup?
I don't know how differential backup on 2/2/2021 would know about all the changes since 1/1/2021

Comment: Assuming you have a full backup that you can confirm works properly and the differential backup you need you'll be fine.  If someone else took the most recent full backup and put it somewhere that you don't know about you'll have issues.

Comment: Diff backups contain all changed pages since the last full backup, not since the last diff backup

Answer (score 0):

"If I restore full backup with norecovery, would I be able to restore 2/2/2021 differential backup?" --- YES

"how differential backup on 2/2/2021 would know about all the changes since 1/1/2021" --- through bitmap . "The differential backup operation relies on a bitmap page that contains a bit for every extent. For each extent updated since the base, the bit is set to 1 in the bitmap."